# Access TabContent's tab and it's content JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tabs, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a question regarding TabContent.
So I create the tabs dynamically like this:

```
private Tab addNewTab(final TabPane tabPane, String newTabName, Node newTabContent, boolean isCloseable) {
    Tab newTab = new Tab(newTabName);
    newTab.setContent(newTabContent);
    newTab.setClosable(isCloseable);

    newTab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            if (tabPane.getTabs()
                    .size() == 2) {
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });

    tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);
    return newTab;

}
```

And my question would be, how do I access the newTabContent Node.
I have tried something like this:

```
object.getTabPane().getTabs().get(0).getContent()
```

But this doesn't return me the Node with all of it's attributes.

For example if the Node is another object, I cannot access it's attributes (buttons, fields etc). I would like to do something like this:

```
object.getTabPane().getTabs().get(0).getContent().getMyTextField().getText();
```

I can provide more information if required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "But this doesn't return the Node". I'm pretty sure it does. What do you mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of a tab is to contain a whole layout and inside this layout you can get the Node you want but for your example of `TextField`:

```
//Here return the TextField
TextField tf = (TextField) tab.getContent();
```

Personally I would have stored my `Tabs` in a `List<Tab>`, with a layout (`Pane`) as content for my other `Nodes`. In my humble opinion I think it's easier like that !

```
//Create dynamic tabs
List<Tab> tabs = new ArrayList<>();
Pane pane = new Pane();
TextField tf = new TextField("Hi");
pane.getChildren.add(tf);
tabs.add(addNewTab(tabPane, "Test", pane, true));
```

**Note :** That doesn't mean that the Tab can't contain other nodes !